# Refreshing the page reloads POST action

Tags: php, mysql, forms, post

I have a modal popup in which I've put in the form which will allow to create the new contact person for a specific account. The modal works fine, the form works great, however once I click the button it goes back to what has been shown on the contacts list before the new contact has been created. I've obviously cliked F5 to refresh the page and the box came up asking whether I'm sure that I want to reload the form. Clicked yes, and it showed me the contact that has been added, but in the background it has added another one with the same details.

How to avoid that ? Do I have to clear the POST or put some kind of reload the page function to the button or the function I'm using to create the contact ?

This is the part of the code that I'm running :

```
Class Client {

    var $_newcontact;
    ...

    public function AddContact() {
        switch($this->_newcontact) {
            case "BackEnd":
                $this->GetData_NewContact();
                if($this->ValidateNewContact()==true) {
                    if($this->AddNewContact($_GET['ClientID'])==true) {
                        echo "New contact has been added";
                    } else {
                        echo "Contact hasn't been created";
                    }
                }
        }
    }

}
```

On the new_contact page I use the code :

```
$Client= new Client();
if($_POST['NewContact']) {
    $Client->_newcontact = "BackEnd";
    $Client->AddContact();
}
```

There there's also a form in the Modal (i'm using bootstrap modal actually). I guess code for this is not needed.

Then the button code :

```
  <button type="submit" value="submit" name="NewContact" id="NewContact" class="btn btn-primary">Add</button>
```

I would like to make sure that once the Add button has been clicked, and full validation of data is set to true etc, then it will reload the page with the list of the contacts and show the contact that has been added ( I have a loop that takes them from the database).

How do I accomplish that ?

Comment: You need to use POST-redirect-GET. Refreshing after that will refresh the GET, which causes no prompts.

Answer (score 0):

"however once I click the button".  if this is a jquery modal I assume this is the "Complete" button in the modal.

in the Complete function of the modal you can do:

```
            "Complete": function() 
            {
                  window.location.replace('index.php');
            }
```

replacing index.php with whatever page you want.